# Structure of the solutions of the matricial ODE: $\dot U(t) = -U^2 - BU$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, svd, banach-algebras, gradient-flows

Let $A$ and $B$ be a fixed $n \times n$ positive semi-definite matrices. Given an $n \times n$ matrix $U$, define another $n \times n$ matrix by $F(U) := U^2 + U B$. Consider the ODE

$$
\dot U(t) = -F(U(t)),\, U(0) = A.
$$
Define $U_\infty := \lim_{t \to \infty} U(t)$.

**Question.** In terms of $B$, can anything be said about the eigenvalue decomposition of $U_\infty$ ?

Comment: Let's try the Riccati approach, let $Y$ be an "exponential" of $U$, a solution of $\dot Y=YU$. Then $$\ddot Y =Y\dot U+\dot YU=-Y(U^2+UB)+YU^2=-YUB=-\dot YB.$$

As $B$ is constant, the solution of the last equation is $$\dot Y(t)=\dot Y(0)\exp(-tB)$$ with integral $$Y(t)-Y(0)=Y(0)At\phi_1(-tB).$$ Finally, compute $U(t)=Y(t)^{-1}\dot Y(t)$. While that gives an explicit solution, it is not obvious how that translates to the signs of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Since the ODE is autonomous $F(U_\infty)$ has to be the zero matrix. Thus $U_\infty^2=-U_\infty B$. Maybe this helps. For example, if $U_\infty$ is invertible, then $U_\infty=-B$.

Comment: Thanks Lutz and Gerd. Those are helpful remarks and definitely help.